# Conversion rate models for multi-touch digital advertising over time

Tags: reference-request, demand, advertising

Is there any literature on the conversion rate of multi-touch advertising over time, showing that how decreasing the time between touches increases conversion rate?

For example, a chart showing:

- Y-axis: Conversion rate
- X-axis: Time (hours or days) between touches

I found this but it seems to be focused on evaluating different models for predictions.  I'm looking for more of a standard:  https://eprints.bbk.ac.uk/id/eprint/16166/1/CIKM2016_582.pdf

I'm trying to evaluate the demand captured by moving touches closer together.